# Incorrect Syntax or misunderstanding powershell Do until loop

Tags: variables, powershell, switch-statement, wildcard

I'm currently writing a script to prompt for user input, but want to continue prompting the user until a workstation\IP address  or username is entered. This will be implemented into a larger more robust script but i can't get this portion working. Is my syntax off or am I misunderstanding the logic, probably both.

- `D????-*` is our corporate workstation naming standard (ie `DOUAW-7811652`)
- `*-admin` refers to administrator accounts that are not supported by the larger script

The code looks like this so far:

```
Function Admin{
Write-host "Admin Accounts are not supported" -ForegroundColor Red
}

Function Workstation{
Write-Host "Workstation $name"
$workstation = $true
}

Function UserName{
Write-Host "User Name $name"
$UserName = $true
}

DO {
$Name = Read-Host "Please enter the User Name or Workstation(or IP)"

switch -Wildcard ($name){
"*-admin" {Admin}
"D????-*"{Workstation}
"*.*.*.*"{Workstation}
Default {UserName}
}

}

until ($UserName -eq "$true" -or $workstation -eq "$true")

Read-Host "Press any key to exit"
```

Comment: Your variables $username and $workstation are scoped to within the functions. You need them to be scoped at the script level at a minimum. At a command prompt type: Get-Help Scope

Comment: Reading up on Scope as I type, Thank you for the information, may take a bit for this to all soak in.

Comment: The answer you accepted is perfectly good. It uses the function returns to get the result back to the scope within the Do loop.

Comment: Actually, just to be clear, the solution you accepted is more elegant because it is more decoupled than using a script or globally scoped variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(While I might not have written it like this, I just fixed code so you could get out of your infinite loop)

You might want something like

```
Function Workstation{
    Write-Host "Workstation $name"
    return $true
}

Function UserName{
    Write-Host "User Name $name"
    return $true
}
DO {
    $Name = Read-Host "Please enter the User Name or Workstation(or IP)"

    switch -Wildcard ($name){
    "*-admin" {Admin}
    "D????-*"{$workstation = Workstation}
    "*.*.*.*"{$workstation = Workstation}
    Default {$UserName = UserName}
    }
} until ($UserName -eq "$true" -or $workstation -eq "$true")
```

Comment: BTW, indentation when writing code, is your best friend :)

Comment: This did work for me, and gave me the results desired, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mean:
`until ($UserName -eq $true -or $workstation -eq $true)`

(Note no quotes around `$true`.)

Comment: With or without quotes the result is the same, and endless loop prompting for a response without ever making it to "Press any key to exit"

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say that this would be a good use of an advanced function. Define your parameters in a way that they do all the validation and enforce requirements. Something like this would get you very close to what you are looking for.

```
Function Do-Something
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Username")]
    param(

        [Parameter(
            Mandatory         = $true,
            HelpMessage       = "Please enter a username",
            Position          = 0,
            ParameterSetName  = "Username",
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
            )]
        [string[]]$Username,

        [Parameter(
            Mandatory         = $true,
            HelpMessage       = "Please enter a computername",
            Position          = 0,
            ParameterSetName  = "Computername",
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
            )]
        [ValidatePattern('D\w\w\w\w-|(\d+\.){3}\d+')]
        [string[]]$ComputerName

    )
    process
    {
        if($Username){Username}
        if($ComputerName){Computername}
    }
}

Show-Command Do-Something
```